# internal-package Error 2 while building in Theos

Tags: objective-c, package, building, theos

I keep getting make: * [internal-package] Error 2 when trying to build a tweak im working on. Ive never had this issue before, and its not specifying whats wrong. Here is what it says:

```
Ethans-Mac-mini:alienblue ethanarbuckle$ sudo make package
/Users/ethanarbuckle/Desktop/alienblue/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin/iphone.mk:46: Deploying to iOS 3.0 while building for 6.0 will generate armv7-only binaries.
Making all for tweak AlienBlue...
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `internal-library-compile'.
Making stage for tweak AlienBlue...
dpkg-deb: building package `com.ethanarbuckle.alienblue++' in `./com.ethanarbuckle.alienblue++_0.0.1-9_iphoneos-arm.deb'.
make: *** [internal-package] Error 2
```

Can anyone shed some light on whats happening?

Comment: Use: make package messages=yes to show the error message.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

This is because dpkg won't build a package that has a identifier that isn't alphanumeric (e.g. only A-Z, a-z, 0-9) so it is rejecting the "++" in your package id. I suggest make a new tweak in the NIC and copy your "Tweak.xm" to the new tweak folder and give it an id something like com.ethanarbuckle.alienblueplusplus instead of com.ethanarbuckle.alienblue++.

I had the same error and it took me about a month to figure it out. This change worked for me. Don't forget when you make a new tweak in the NIC to re-add any frameworks you had imported.

Your package name, however, can still have the ++ in it.